# How to change Material UI component property according to props

Tags: reactjs, validation, material-ui, react-forms

This is my react js code with MUI **TextField** and I need  to apply **error** and **helperText** property when error prop has a value. default error prop value is null.

```
import React from 'react'
import { TextField } from '@mui/material'

const InputField = (props) => {

const { name, label, value,error=null, onChange } = props;

  return (
    <TextField
        variant='outlined'
        label={label}
        name={name}
        value={value}
        onChange={onChange}
        {...{error && {error:true,helperText:error}}}
    />
  )
}

export default InputField
```

The error is on this line. How I figer it on MUI 5.10.9 version

```
{...{error && {error:true,helperText:error}}}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `error` and `helperText` prop directly without condition. also use `space` character inside helperText to avoid height issue when there is no error present. https://mui.com/material-ui/react-text-field/#helper-text

```
<TextField
  variant='outlined'
  label={label}
  name={name}
  value={value}
  onChange={onChange}
  error={!!error}
  helperText={error || ' '}
/>
```

Comment: Grate. I use this code for helper text  `helperText={error ===null ? '':error}` it also work for me.